# passing hidden input value by using php

Tags: php, forms

The code should show the value in the function when I click "submit". Here is the code below:

```
  <form method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="HDN_FormClicked" value= <?php echo $clicked ?> />
   <?php 
   if($_POST){
     $clicked= "You have clicked the button";}
     ?>
  <input class="button" type="submit"/>
  </form>
```

Do I need to use $_get to make the code work?

Comment: What is your `<form>`'s method?

Comment: value= <?php echo $clicked ?> should be, value= '<?php echo $clicked ?>'

Comment: method="post" I will update it to the question

Comment: Do you have a submit button, or any other way to submit the form?

Comment: No, add ' 'doesn't help, still nothing in it.

Comment: Yes, I have submit button.

Comment: On the first load of the page, $clicked does not have any values. You should assign default value

Comment: If I'm not wrong, I assume, you want that when you click this button, the value will be automatically updated. If you need that, use some JavaScript. Moreover, place this piece of code if($_POST){
     $clicked= "You have clicked the button";}
     ?> before 
  <input type="hidden" name="HDN_FormClicked" value= <?php echo $clicked ?> />

Comment: pls edit your question as because ,for new visitors get rid of errors

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit_button']))
       $clicked = 'You have clicked the button';

?>

<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="HDN_FormClicked" value="<?php echo (isset($clicked)) ?  $clicked : '' ?>" />
<input class="button" name="submit_button" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

alternative

```
<?php 
    $clicked = '';

    if(isset($_POST['submit_button'])) 
       $clicked = 'You have clicked the button'; 
?>

<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="HDN_FormClicked" value="<?= $clicked?>" />
<input class="button" name="submit_button" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Nice. It worked! I am trying to replace the php code to function, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you have in your code looks like mixing javascript with php...

If you want to pass values from your form to PHP you can use:

`<form action="phpfile.php" method="post">`

and on your php file you can "use" the values using `$_POST`.

Example:

```
<form action="http://somesite.com/prog/adduser" method="post">
<input type="text" name="info_to_get_1" value="" />
<input type="text" name="info_to_get_2" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Send">
```

and in your php file:

```
$value_1 = $_POST["info_to_get_1"];
$value_2 = $_POST["info_to_get_2"];
```

In your case if you want to have info if user has clicked, you should write your example something like this:

`if(isset($_POST["HDN_FormClicked"])){$clicked= "You have clicked the button";}`

Answer (score 0):

Pluto, your issue is that you are trying to use the variable $clicked before it is actually defined. Why are you passing php code through the value attribute of a hidden element? Your approach seems convoluted. Read up on standard procedures for creating a form and posting it.

Comment: This actually a validation code. For example, when one field is blank, the error message should be "invalid field". I have finished the basic codes by using php, but the error message is shown on the bottom. So I tried to them on the top.

Comment: Use javascript for client side validation. It's not fool proof - but will save a lot of headaches. Either way - do your best to avoid embedded php code in the midst of HTML. It's messy and considered bad practice - and will only serve to confuse you, the developer.

Answer (score 0):

Here a small example of form submitting:

```
<form method="POST" action="/form.php" name="myForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="myHiddenValue" value="<?php echo $clicked ?>" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type in some text" name="myText" value="" />
    <button name="mySubmit" type="submit">Submit the form!</button>
</form>

<?php
    $clicked = "not_clicked";
    if ($_POST) {
        if (isset($_POST['myForm']) && isset($_POST['mySubmit'])) {
            $clicked = "clicked";
            var_dump($_POST); // dumps your $_POST array.
        }
    }
?>
```

Explanation:

With the method attribute you change the request method. In this case POST, but you can have GET.
The action attribute sets the location to where your form data will be sent. 
The hidden type in the input hides the input.
With the name attribute you 'name' the form and the form fields.